# Prove that sequence is decreasing. Is my proof correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It has been proven that $2\leq x_n\leq 3$ for all n.

Let $(x_n)$ be given by $x_1=2.5$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6)$ for $n>1$ Show that the sequence is decreasing.

Proof by induction:

Base case: $x_1=2.5 \geq 2.45=x_2$

Inductive step: Assume $x_n \leq x_{n-1}$ so $\frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6)\leq x_{n-1}$

Now because of this $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{5}(x_{n}^2+6)=\frac{1}{5}((\frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6))^2+6)\leq \frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6)=x_n$

Thus $x_{n+1}\leq x_n$ and the sequence is decreasing. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is incomplete. A little detail about how you know $$\frac{1}{5}((\frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6))^2+6)\leq \frac{1}{5}(x_{n-1}^2+6)$$ would be nice - I don't see how you can simply claim this inequality holds.

---

Instead of using induction, it's easier to just look at the sign of the expression $x_n-x_{n-1}$ and prove the expression is negative.

Comment: It has been proven that $2\leq x_n\leq 3$ for all n. Does that help?

Comment: @LearnMore Yes, but in that case, you don't really need induction. Just llook at the value $x_n - x_{n-1}$ and prove it is negative.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! :)